# Generate password list with specific keywords and length

Tags: passwords, wifi, password-cracking

I need to generate a list of passwords to try penetrating into a wi-fi network. I have a pretty big list of keywords and I want to use them to generate as many possible passwords as possible, which will be in a specific range in length.

For example I need a password with keywords "dog", "cat", "bird", "sun", "tree" with length from 4 to 10, so my password list will include passwords like: birdcat, suncat, suncatdog, treebird etc.

I've read the documentation of Crunch tool, but it doesn't look like what I need. Maybe I'm wrong. So I ask you if it is possible to generate such lists and what tools should I use (I use Linux Kali and Mac OS if it is necessary information) and how it can be done?
Thanks

Comment: crunch can do what you're asking, but so could a simple script

Comment: @schroeder but how? I see only the option where you include words and it combines all of them, I have no idea how to limit the length. Any suggestions?

Comment: from: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/crunch.1.html `max-len`

Comment: @schroeder Example 8:
`crunch 4 5 -p dog cat bird`
The numbers **aren't processed** but are needed. crunch will generate birdcatdog,  birddogcat...

Comment: I'm not a crunch expert but I think that `-p` is not the right flag to be using here. You may need to just write a script. It doesn't need to be that clever.

Answer (score 1):

The most precise and flexible mechanism to perform a combinator attack with multiple combination lengths plus length restrictions is probably to combine [princeprocessor](https://github.com/hashcat/princeprocessor) with the [len](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat_utils#len) utility from hashcat-utils:

```
$ cat list.txt
dog
cat
bird
sun
tree

$ pp64 <list.txt | len 4 10
bird
tree
dogdog
catdog
sundog
dogcat
catcat
suncat
dogsun
catsun
[...]
birdcatcat
treecatcat
birdsuncat
treesuncat
birddogsun
treedogsun
birdcatsun
treecatsun
birdsunsun
treesunsun
```

You don't mention whether there is a minimum number of elements (words); princeprocessor has options for that as well.

While efficiency isn't as much of an issue for a slow hash like WPA2, `pp64` and `len` are optimized for high speed, and so are also useful for faster hashes as well.